# How to transfer session from one Tomcat server to another?

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket

We have a Tomcat server for a web shop, and we need to transfer the user to another (secure) server when he/she logs in. Here's a detailed explanation:

1) We have two Tomcat servers: one 'regular' (HTTP) and one secure (HTTPS)

2) Users initially visit the regular server

3) When they log in, we need to get their log in data, as well as the information about what page they were currently on (or were trying to see), pass it to the secure server and do the actual login; for instance, a non-logged in user sees a list of products, clicks 'BUY' and a popup is displayed, asking the user to log in; the user enters his/hers credentials and these, as well as the information about what product he wants to buy, are passed to the secure server; the secure server receives these, performs the login and displays the requested product to the user

How could this be done? Please note the following:

1) We've tried doing it with cookies, but we've decided not to go that way

2) Persisting the session to a database and then having the secure server fetch it is also not an option

Are there any other ways? We were thinking about creating an object and then passing it as a HTTP POST parameter, but I'm not sure how this could be done (I've been given the task to finish it).

For what it's worth, the technologies we use are Tomcat server, Wicket, Spring, iBatis and MySQL.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can I ask why you've decided against cookies? Every site I've been on that needed to track user sessions across multiple web servers has used cookies. You set a cookie with a unique id for the user and if the cookie exists look up your user session in the db. Which your second note kills.

Comment: The problem is in the second note. We do not want to use the database, so we would have to save the user's username, password and the information about what he/she clicked in a cookie (or more of them). Keeping usernames and passwords in cookies is a security risk... Unless these can somehow be secured?

Comment: Don't keep the username password in the cookie. Put a unique session id in the cookie that in your db is associated both with the ip address of the user and the user account. Also make the cookie expire with his browser session.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that's not the way I can go with this. We don't have a session server, and we also don't want to keep the session in the SQL server that the application uses. And, since I can't keep the username and password in the cookies, I have to tell the non-secure server to create an object that holds all the information and then pass it to the secure server. If you have any ideas on how I could do this, I'd be very grateful :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share the session between different Tomcat instances, you could configure them to work as a cluster with session replication: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html

Then, you could configure an Apache HTTP Server to work as a load balancer, making sure that HTTP requests go to server 1 and HTTPS requests go to server 2.

But, you could also have only one Tomcat instance (or N identical instances) configured to handle both HTTP and HTTPS, and ensure the secure access with standard (`...<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>...` in web.xml) or framework-specific configuration.

Comment: Hi, me again :) Sorry for not replying sooner, I've been a bit busy. The things I have to add are these: cookies cannot be used, because the non-secure and the secure server will be on different domains. Speck's idea was my favourite, and I started implementing it, but since it uses cookies, I can't use it. So, instead, I'll try to set the login form on the web shop to submit its contents directly to the secure server. To be honest, I'm not sure how to do this. What I did try to do so far was to "inject" all the parameters I needed into the RequestCycle...

Comment: ... For this, I extended RedirectRequestTarget and tried to insert the request parameters into the Request itself. I've also noticed that you can only add cookies to the Response. Anyway, to cut the story short, the parameters all get lost once I reach the secure server. If anyone has any idea on this, again, I'd like to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm getting the gist of what you want but you could have the "pop-up" be a page served from the secure application to a protected URL.  That would cause the authentication to occur at the secure server and you could go from there.  For example, if the unsecured product page is on www.domain.com/browse/id1, then the "buy" button would open a pop-up to secure.domain.com/buy/id1, causing the authentication while transmitting the product id on the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your help, people :) I've found that Wicket has a RedirectPage. I create it by passing the secure-server URL to the constructor and then doing redirectToInterceptPage(redirectPage), but the problem is that whatever I do, I can't add any parameters/properties to the redirectPage. I can't seem to pass neither RequestParameters nor PageParameters to the redirectPage, and then to the secure server (they all end up being null).