# session maintaince for two applications

Tags: java, servlets, session-state, sessionid

I have a web application `say A`, 
When i login in this application its home page contains a Link,

when i click on that link, I am getting login into another web application `Say B` and it open in to a **`iframe` within the home page of A.**

**Both the applications are deployed on different server** .

Now when i click on any link/Button within the B application `(iframe in A)` `session` of B application expires.

To maintain the session, I rewrite the url of B application by **appending session id** to it.

By doing thatit is login in.

But, when i use `request.getSession()` always i am getting **new object**.

i want **previous session** object because i have values in session object.

Is their any way so that i can maintain the session.???

Thanks

Comment: what frameworks and servers do you use?

Comment: i am using tomcat , sturts1 and i have no access to code of application A

Answer (score 0):

Think of session as a Map that is created for each user on the web application.

Meaning, session1 that belongs to WebApp-A is local to that application and session2 that belongs to WebApp-B is local to that application.

The jsessionId that you see in the URL is a key used by the application server to identify the session object for that webapp.

So, in your case, you need to think about sharing data through other means:

1. If you just want to access some key/value pair, then pass it through the URL as a request parameter.
2. If you want to access an object, then consider using a shared storage - like a database; or a distributed cache
3. If all you want is that the user be logged in to both the applications, then you need a Single Sign On solution

From the looks of your question, you just want the user to be logged in to both applications with one challenge. Read up on SSO solutions.

The session objects will be different.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This Stackoverflow question discusses some relevant things.

[How to transfer session from one Tomcat server to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553172/how-to-transfer-session-from-one-tomcat-server-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to you need inject one more layer in your application, some kind of session manager. Since, you don't have an ability to modify `app B`, you should modify your 'app A'. But in this you would be the hostage of situation. Another bad thing, is question what you have to do in case of addition of one more `app C`.

Well, Harsha R already mentioned SSO solution. You can implement one on `app A` level, some session manager as I said before. For example, request `app B` through your special `Servlet` in cooperation with `Filter` feature you could substitute `Http-Headers` to support seamless `JSESSIONID` (and another session holding stuff) managing between different applications.

Answer (score 0):

If session tracking mode is `COOKIE` than you might try changing cookie name so that they'd be different for the two apps:

```
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
      <!-- change below -->
      <name>web-app-A</name>
      <path>/</path>
      <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
  </session-config>
```